# Proper way to import modules using the template below in python3

Tags: python

I am trying to adopt good practices when writing code and organizing files. One of my recent project has the template as follows, I have no issue running the code, but `pylint` is complaining, and I believe I am doing something wrong, my simplified template is as follows:

```
├── config
│   ├── config.py               <- config
│   ├── global_params.py        <- global config
│
├── src
│   ├── main.py       <- main file to run
│   ├── trainer.py    <- Training
│   ├── utils.py      <- util functions
```

When I run my scripts, I do:

```
python src/main.py
```

What I am concerned about is my imports, I have two questions:

1. In `global_params.py`, I need to use some functions in `config.py`. As such, I simply did `from config import config` in `global_params.py`. `pylint` immediately complains about `no name ... in module` error, so I put a `init.py` file in the folder to curb this issue, is this a good practice? Or should I rename `config.py` to some other names to not clash with the folder name.
2. In `src/main.py`, I also encounted issues when running the codes. Sometimes it worked, and sometimes it doesn't. I read from online a quick fix as follows:

   ```
   BASE_DIR = (Path(__file__).parent.parent.absolute().__str__())  
   sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)

   from src import utils, trainer
   from config import config, global_params
   ```

I have seen others say this may cause potential issues, and thus would like to know what is the recommended way to import files from other folders. Many answers on StackOverflow uses `sys`.

Comment: Generally, if you have a folder with one or more scripts and will be importing, it's a good idea to add an `__init__.py` file, there's nothing wrong with that. You'll likely want one in your `src` folder as well. Messing around with the PATH to make imports work shouldn't be necessary, I would definitely consider that an anti-pattern. There's also the issue that while it might work at runtime, tools like linters aren't going to resolve the imports correctly.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks, I have added both now and it works. In that case, is my `from src import ..` and `from config import ..` considered a good practice? I have seen some big libraries do relative imports like `from .. import ..` which I am unable to do so effectively.

Comment: better to create a main file outside src folder and then from that file run the project